# Facing issue with Selenium Chrome web driver in wpf c#

Tags: c#, wpf, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

Trying to write automation scripts in wpf c# but not able to launch chrome and also it is not throwing any error, where as in console project, I am able to launch the chrome and also able to write scripts.

```
ChromeOptions options=new ChromeOptions();
options.AddAdditionalCapability("useAutomationExtention",false);
options.AddArgument("--DNS-prefetch-disable");
ChromeDriver _driver=new ChromeDriver(options); //Stucking here in wpf project but it is wrking fine in Console project
_driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://www.google.co.in")
```

Can anyone help me with this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I happened to use Selenium for some other purpose, but the general idea of launching chrome should be the same I guess. Here's how it's working in my case (done as async to free the UI of course):

```
        public async Task StartBrowser()
    {
        await Task.Run(() =>
        {
            ChromeOptions op = InitializeOptions();
            var chromeDriverService = ChromeDriverService.CreateDefaultService();
            chromeDriverService.HideCommandPromptWindow = true;
            driver = new ChromeDriver(chromeDriverService, op);
            // Add optional driver handling procedures (like timeout management)

        }); 
    }


    private ChromeOptions InitializeOptions()
    {
        ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();

      // Your set of options
            return options;
    }


    public async Task CloseBrowser()
    {
       await Task.Run(()=> driver.Quit()) ;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks Pawel, It is working now, Also i am trying to attach existing chrome window to selenium web driver, do you have any idea how can we implement this

Comment: As far as I know, It's not possible to just attach to existing chrome window.
Information from selenium git comment section: 
"With IE, it's possible to iterate over the open windows in the OS and find the right IE process to attach to.
Firefox and Chrome, OTOH, need to be started in a specific mode and configuration, which means that just attaching to a running instance isn't technically possible."
 Maybe there is some way to go around, but unfortunately I cannot help here.